# Javascript alert window - how to set len

Tags: javascript, window, alert

I've got a basic HTML/JavaScript contact form that HostGator provided. It works pretty well...if user submits no name or invalid email address, a JavaScript alert pops-up that says so. These alerts stay on the screen until user clicks OK. However, if user submits contact form correctly, the final success alert only lasts for 1/2 a second or so. I'm trying to figure out how to make the final email success alert last for a specified time, either that or until user clicks on the OK button at which point they are redirected to specified page. Here is the link to the HostGator info on contact form w/ JavaScript http://www.hostgator.com/formmail.shtml and here is the code which I'm trying to change to get post-submit JavaScript message to stick around instead of disappearing before the user even has a chance to read it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>FormMail Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hgsubmit()
{
if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.name.value) == false) alert ("Please provide your name.");
else if (/^\S+@[a-z0-9_.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i.test(document.hgmailer.email.value) == false) alert ("A valid email address is required.");
 else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.comment.value) == false) alert ("Your email content is needed.");
  else {
       document.hgmailer.submit();
       alert ('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
       }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://www.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" name="hgmailer">
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="myemail@mydomain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="FormMail E-Mail">
Whatever you want to say here<br><br>
Visitor Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="30" value=""><br>
Visitor E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email" size="30" value=""><br>
E-Mail Content: <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="button" value="E-Mail Me!" onclick="hgsubmit();">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.mydomain.com/redirect-path">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try putting alert() before submit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   else {
     alert('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
     setTimeout("document.hgmailer.submit()", 4*1000);
   }
```

This should do the alert(), wait 4 seconds (or whatever you specify in the second paramter) and then do the submit().

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems that popup is shown while `document.hgmailer.submit();` is still in process. Because of delay in submit, you see popup window for a fraction of second before `submit()` completes and you are redirected to target page.

One way is to put `alert(....)` before `....submit()`, or you can use jQuery to asynchronously post you data like:

```
    $.post("target_Page_Address", 
            { var1: value1, var2: value2 // and so on }, 
            function(response){  // Do something based on response }
          );
```

EDIT:

Or you can avoid this whole popup business and do this:

```
    document.hgmailer.submit_button_name.value= 'Please wait...';
    document.hgmailer.submit();
```

That is, you can  basically set the `value` of Submit button to `"Please wait..."` from `"Email Me!"`

this way, users will know that their email is still being processed and they won't change the page before completion.

Comment: Thanks. This answer was a bit more educational than the others, but did not address my question (my subjective opinion) in the most efficient simple manner. Appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily stop the form submitting till the user click the 'ok' button of the last alert.
use

```
alert ('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
//waits here  until user click 'ok', then submit!
document.hgmailer.submit();
```

instead,

```
document.hgmailer.submit();
alert ('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
```

Comment: Thanks! It's another good way to accomplish what I was trying for.